# The rate of didUpdate callbacks when using ARKit face tracking

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

Checking feasibility of eye tracking with ARKit for a new application. 
We would like to record the point on screen (along with time stamp) that the user looks at, using an iOS device with the True Depth capabilities.
I have 2 questions:

1. Is there some guarantee on the rate that `renderer:didUpdate` is called. Do we know for example that it is called at least 30 times per second?
2. In all examples that i saw, using ARKit face tracking requires SceneKit, is there an option to use face tracking without SceneKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**.

It's a pity but there's no guarantee that your app can render a scene at 60 fps, there's also no guarantee that your app can render it at 30 fps. You could set up a rendering frame rate using [preferredFramesPerSecond](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink/1648421-preferredframespersecond) instance property...

```
var preferredFramesPerSecond: Int { get set }
```

or:

```
@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
sceneView.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30
```

...but it depends on a bunch of factors (especially on how many high-poly models, PBR shaders and shadows your scene has). Hence, you need to choose a frame rate that your app can consistently maintain.

> The default value of `preferredFramesPerSecond` is 0. When this value is 0, the preferred frame rate is equal to the maximum refresh rate of the display, as indicated by the maximumFramesPerSecond property.

**Second**.

Apart from SceneKit framework, for face tracking you can also use a brand-new framework named [RealityKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit). But frankly speaking, I haven’t tried yet `eye tracking`, or so called `gaze detection`, in context of RealityKit.